# server-side PHP code to process the form to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form (on page form.php) and when the submit button is clicked it sends the data to mysql using:

```
  <form name="food."; action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" >
```

I now want to submit it to mysql then go to 'thankyou.php' page. So I need a server side PHP code to process the form to mysql.

```
  <form name="food."; action="thankyou.php" method="post" >
```

thankyou.php will submit the form then display 'thank you, your form has been submitted'.

What would the code need to be on the thankyou.php page to submit the form data on the form.php page.

Comment: Dude, you're missing php basics, you should google for php form control tutorials like this one http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-tutorial.html btw: is this a homework?

Comment: Basically the exact question text as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9165182/prevent-form-from-reloading-when-validation-error-occurs-jquery  You really should learn basic HTTP form handling before going for "fancy" stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You should go through some basic tutorials for it: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Here is sample code :

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","peter","abc123");
    if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }

    mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);

    $sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
    VALUES
    ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[age]')";

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
      {
      die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
      }
   header("Location:thankyou.php");

    mysql_close($con)
    ?>
```

Comment: I have followed this tutorial, my code is here http://pastebin.com/DCJTjCPr . Im getting error 'Not Submitted'. All field names are correct. It is connecting to the db but not storing the data. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: you should quote all passed values properly. Like : '".$_POST[attendance1]."','".$_POST[colour1]."',.....

Comment: $sql="INSERT INTO user (attendance1, colour1, shade1, attendance2, colour2, shade2)
VALUES
('".$_POST[attendance1]."','".$_POST[colour1]."','".$_POST[shade1]."','".$_POST[attendance2]."','".$_POST[colour2]."','".$_POST[shade2]."')";

Comment: ok got it working however it creates a new record in mydql. how do I just update the record?

Comment: just go through tutorials for updating records. use UPDATE query for that

Comment: I have a login and once a user logs in they fill out the form which updates the fields next to their username and password on the database

Comment: it will be better you post that in separate question or google for related.We can't do every thing like this way.

Comment: @user1188711 :If whatever you asked in this question is worked by this answer you can accept it

Comment: it did not work as I have a login. This just inserts a new record to the datbase. not what im looking for

Comment: see after login for update you need to do totally different from what you asked here. you need to create session and take logged user's id from sessin then you need to do stuff for update record for that id. All these are not possible to do here. Just google or go for some tutorials for it. Let me find it for you

Comment: check this link . explained every thing : http://www.roscripts.com/PHP_login_script-143.html

Answer (score 1):

you Are using the

```
    <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>
```

meaning you are sending that on the same page,

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //validate your post
    if (post validated)
    insert to database
    use the header("location:thankyou.php");


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First setup your database connection, this information is best saved in a separate file

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

depending on what your form fields are, these would need to be added to the database with an INSERT Query

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-insert-query.htm

Then use

```
header("Location:thankyou.php");
```

(make sure there is no html before the redirect)

You don't need to another form